# Strava API v3 PHP doesn't deliver anything using a get query

Tags: php

It might be a dumb question but I have been stuck for a while now, I'm sorry for my terrible English.

I am writing an application that can download all information about all Strava activities.

After some debugging I found out that my query isn't returning any data.

The query that I use is:

```
$api->get('activities/XXX/streams/latlng');
```

I found out that it wasn't working because I get `NULL` when I am using `var_dump`

The documentation can be found here: http://strava.github.io/api/

I hope I gave enough information, otherwise just ask for it.

Thanks

Comment: You should add some note about what strata is, where the documentation of that API is and also post more of your code than just a single line. Where does `$api` come from, for example? What does it contain? Is there any error handling done on your side? What does your error log file contain?

Comment: Did you [authenticate properly and supply an `access_token`](https://strava.github.io/api/)?

Comment: Yes i did. I can even show general information about the athlete. But I can't figure out how to retreve a stream like shown on this page http://strava.github.io/api/v3/streams/#activity